# Open Multiple Files from Variable location using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I want to open 4 different Excel files saved under same folder using VBA code, but the folder path is not fixed.

Let's say, I have 4 Excel files named A.xlsx, B.xlsx, C.xlsx & D.xlsx under folder named 22-Feb-15 (This folder name will change everyday, but the file names will remain same).

I want VBA code so that I can select the folder manually and once it is selected, all 4 files will open one by one (there are other files too, but I need to open only these 4 files).

Comment: Is the folder always named as "today"? (e.g. tomorrow it will be 22-Feb-15, the day after 23-Feb-15 etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

Please see below:

```
Sub FolderSelect()
Dim intResult As Integer
Dim fldrPath As String
intResult = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).Show
    If intResult <> 0 Then
        fldrPath = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).SelectedItems(1)
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=fldrPath & "\" & "A.xlsx"
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=fldrPath & "\" & "B.xlsx"
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=fldrPath & "\" & "C.xlsx"
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=fldrPath & "\" & "D.xlsx"
    End If
End Sub
```

You can change file names and/or add new files by following the same structure